# How can i call and print an array from another Package on Java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

```
public void db_access() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // Declaring variables for used by :
    int id[] = new int[15];
    String[] title = new String[16];
    String genre[] = new String[16];
    BigDecimal price[] = new BigDecimal[16];
  }}
```

the code above is from a Package "db" on class "db". how can i (for example) print the second array of "title" on a package called "main" and a class called "start" below?

```
    public Start() {
    initComponents();
    db_connect();
}
```

i have already import the package using "import db.db;"

Comment: You can't because it's a local variable.  Local variables are restricted to their local method.  You'd have to use an instance variable or similar to get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance variable for this.  Probably you should supply a "getter" for the variable for better encapsulation.

```
package DB;

public class Db {

  private String[] title = new String[16];

  public String[] getTitles() {
    return title;
  }

  public void db_access() {
     title[0] = "ID";
     title[1] = "Name";
     // etc.
     // Note I do not re-declare "title" with "String []"
     // this uses the existing "title" already declared above
   }
}
```

From another package, you'd:

```
package other;

import DB.Db;

public class Another {
  public static void main( String... args ) {
    Db db = new Db();
    db.access_db();
    String title2 = db.getTitles()[1];  // == "Name"
  }
}
```

Comment: and how can i call, let's say the second string from another Package?, isnt that just filling the array from a different class? i already have the data, i would want to print the second array data (of title) from another package...thanks for the help :)

Comment: See my updated answer. (Not sure what you mean by "filling the array from a different class".  Accessing the class from a different class is the same as using it from a different package, you just add the `import` for a different package.)

Answer (score 0):

db_access() is a method, You need to use an instance variable for call this

```
db db_v = new db();
db_v.db_access();
```

if you want call only "title"

```
public String[] db_access() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // Declaring variables for used by :
    int id[] = new int[15];
    String[] title = new String[16];
    String genre[] = new String[16];
    BigDecimal price[] = new BigDecimal[16];
    return title;
  }

}
```

and in main class

```
db db_v = new db();
String title[]  = db_v.db_access();
```